# How is the value of (list 'quote '5) = ''5 rather than '(quote 5) or '(''5)?

Tags: list, lisp, quote

It seems that Common Lisp does treat `(list 'quote 'x)` in a special way. For example, the value of `(list 'oddp '5)` is `'(oddp 5)` while the value of `(list 'quote '5)` is `''5`. In other words, the quote function seems to be evaluated even though it should be in data mode due to the quote in front of it.

Compare the value of the following expressions:

```
    1. (list 'quote '5) = (list 'quote 5) = (quote '5) = ''5
    2. (list '' '5) = '(''5)
    3. (list ' 5) = (list 5) = '(5)
    4. (list 'oddp '5) != (oddp 5)
```

The evaluation appears to be very idiosyncratic. But I reckon that I might be very confused.

Can someone help me to better understand the pattern here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does *=* mean? You might use it for two different things: equality after read and equality after evaluation. Btw., in Lisp itself the function `=` compares numbers.

**The first step is reading**:

`(list 'quote '5)`  read > `(LIST (QUOTE QUOTE) (QUOTE 5))`

`(list '' '5)`  read > `(LIST (QUOTE (QUOTE (QUOTE 5))))`

`(list ' 5)`  read >  `(LIST (QUOTE 5))`

`(list 'oddp '5)`  read >  `(LIST (QUOTE ODDP) (QUOTE 5))`

Now `'` is a read macro. It transforms the next textual form.  `'someform` is just read as `(QUOTE SOMEFORM)`. The printer may retransform this when printing it. Note how it interacts with pretty printing. The following example is in LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 50 > '(QUOTE SOMEFORM)
(QUOTE SOMEFORM)

CL-USER 51 > (setf *print-pretty* t)
T

CL-USER 52 > '(QUOTE SOMEFORM)
'SOMEFORM
```

Note also that the quote readmacro character `'` reads over whitespace.

`'5` is read the same as for example `'     5` .

But it is good style to put the quote directly in front of the next expression, without whitespace.

**The second step is evaluation**:

`(LIST (QUOTE QUOTE) (QUOTE 5))`  eval >  `(QUOTE 5)`  prettyprint > `'5`

`(LIST (QUOTE (QUOTE (QUOTE 5))))`  eval > `((QUOTE (QUOTE 5)))` prettyprint > `(''5)`

`(LIST (QUOTE 5))`  eval > `(5)`

`(LIST (QUOTE ODDP) (QUOTE 5))`  eval > `(ODDP 5)`

Answer (score 3):

`'X` and `(quote X)` are equivalent, the first is simply a shorthand for the second, and the printer will use that shorthand when serializing it. But no actual evaluation happened in your example. (Evaluating `(quote X)` would give you `X`).

Comment: I am kind of confused that `'quote` and `(quote quote)` are equivalent and both evaluate to `quote`. But when used as a `list` function parameter then `(list 'quote 'quote)` evaluates to `'quote`. Further, `(list 'x)` usually evaluates to `(x)`, i.e. `(cons 'x ())` rather than just `x`.

Comment: `'quote` is **not** equivalent to `quote`. As Rainer mentioned, your examples are very sloppy about evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Re: *For example, the value of `(list 'oddp '5)` is `'(oddp 5)`*

No, it isn't. The value of `(list 'oddp '5)` is just `(oddp 5)`.  No quote.  This is is an object that does happen to be similar to value of the expression `'(oddp 5)`. The two compare `equal`:

```
(equal '(oddp 5) (list 'oddp 5)) -> T
```

Re: *while the value of `(list 'quote '5)` is `''5`.*

This is also not right. The value of `(list 'quote '5)` is the object `(quote 5)` which is notated as `'5`.  The expression `''5` will produce a similar object.

Two expressions that produce identical or similar objects are not always the same thing. `4`, `(+ 2 2)` and `(* 2 2)` are all different objects, but when these pieces of data are treated as code and evaluated, they yield the same value.

Comment: `(list 'quote '5)` evaluates to `(quote '5)` (i.e. `''5` not `(quote 5)`

Comment: In both ANSI Common Lisp and Scheme `(list 'quote '5)` evaluates to `(quote 5)`. You must be using some other dialect.

Comment: @tobydavies Do you still believe that `(list 'quote '5)` produces `(quote '5)`?